# Viper AddConfigPath only finding file in current folder "."

Tags: go

Have code that looks like

```
viper.AddConfigPath(".")
viper.AddConfigPath("$HOME/.config/myprogram")
viper.AddConfigPath("$HOME/configs")
viper.SetConfigFile("myprogram.yaml")
```

If I place myprogram.yaml in the current folder it works. However if I try putting it on either

> $HOME/.config/myprogram
> $HOME/configs

The yaml file is not found. Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [viper docs](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/spf13/viper#SetConfigFile):

> SetConfigFile explicitly defines the path, name and extension of the
> config file. Viper will use this and not check any of the config
> paths.

So if you use `SetConfigFile` the paths will be ignored. Try (as per the [example](https://github.com/spf13/viper/blob/master/README.md#reading-config-files)):

```
viper.SetConfigName("myprogram")
viper.SetConfigType("yaml")
viper.AddConfigPath(".")
viper.AddConfigPath("$HOME/configs")
viper.AddConfigPath("$HOME/.config/myprogram")
```