# Variable for a directory but get error when calling it

Tags: go, viper-go

I'm trying to assign a variable to read a directory but I get this error:

> "cannot use &home (value of type *[]fs.FileInfo) as string value in argument to viper.AddConfigPath"

I also tried the pointer inside `viper.AddConfigPath(&home)` but to no avail as well

Here is a snippet of the code:

```golang
// Find home directory
        home, err := ioutil.ReadDir("../db-dump")
        cobra.CheckErr(err)

        // Search config in home directory with name ".config" (without extension)
        viper.AddConfigPath(home)
```

I'm looking to transform the `type *[]fs.FileInfo` into a string so `viper.AddConfigPath()`can read it.

**Update**

I've tried now this way and I'm getting no error compiling, but I can't really test the code yet because of runtime errors:

```
home := "working directory"
        fileSystem := os.DirFS(home)

        fs.WalkDir(fileSystem, ".", func(path string, d fs.DirEntry, err error) error {
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            fmt.Println(path)
            return nil
        })

        // Search config in home directory with name ".config" (without extension)
        viper.AddConfigPath(home)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that you have type mismatch: `home` is of type `[]fs.FileInfo` ([reference](https://pkg.go.dev/io/ioutil#ReadDir)) while `viper.AddConfigPath()` expects a `string` ([reference](https://gowalker.org/github.com/spf13/viper#AddConfigPath)).

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You can read the error message as:

`cannot use &home` because `value of type *[]fs.FileInfo` is inserted instead of `as string value` ...

Meaning that `viper.AddConfigPath` requires a variable of type `string` and not a pointer to an array of `fs.FileInfo`.

**2.** A quick search here listed [this another topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65431605/viper-addconfigpath-only-finding-file-in-current-folder) that may have the same issue and probably a tip to your question.

Answer (score -1):

first create new config file (just for test code):

```sh
echo "key1: value" > AppName.yaml
```

and run the code

```golang
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/spf13/viper"
)

func main() {
    v := viper.GetViper()
    if err := readConfig(v, ""); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(v.AllKeys())

}

func readConfig(v *viper.Viper, configPath string) error {
    var err error

    if configPath != "" {
        v.SetConfigFile(configPath)
        if err := v.ReadInConfig(); err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("unable to read application config=%q : %w", configPath, err)
        }
        return nil
    }
    // look for .<AppName>.yaml (in the current directory)
    v.AddConfigPath(".")
    v.SetConfigName("AppName")
    if err = v.ReadInConfig(); err == nil {
        return nil
    } else if !errors.As(err, &viper.ConfigFileNotFoundError{}) {
        return fmt.Errorf("unable to parse config=%q: %w", v.ConfigFileUsed(), err)
    }

    return nil
}
```

out:

```sh
[key1]
```

You can load config by path:

```golang
    if err := readConfig(v, "app.yml"); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```